# dreamweaver CS6- windows 8.1-application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

Tags: c#, php, mysql, dreamweaver

I am trying to run  `dreamweaver CS6` in `windows 8.1  64-bit`.

i'm getting this error:

> the application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

Any suggestions please.

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U56vyuT0J38

Answer (score 5):

the problem is your use the version X64 you need use the version X86 of your patch to solve the problem. amtlib.dll

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the following:

Corrupt download or incomplete installation of Adobe Dreamweaver software.

Virus or malware infection that has corrupted Windows system files or Adobe Dreamweaver-related program files.

Corruption in Windows registry from a recent Adobe Dreamweaver-related software change (install or uninstall).

Another program maliciously or mistakenly deleted Adobe Dreamweaver-related files.

Try un-installing, clear adobe leftover files and use a registry cleaner apps.

Re-install adobe, all should be working well and fine !